# How to create a custom error message for a spring boot rest aplication

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I am using Spring Boot to handle REST calls. In this context, I have implemented a controller class with the following method:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<employeeDetails> getEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {
    Optional<Employee> employee = employeeService.getEmployee(id);
    if (employee.isPresent()) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(employee.get());
    } else {
        throw new ApiRequestException("Could not find requested employee");
    }
}
```

I am now sending a request, asking for a non-existent employee. I have verified that the else-block is executed. My issue is that I am not returned a custom error message, instead I see the same old error message in my Browser console that I have seen before implementing the ApiRequestException:

[image: error message]

I cannot understand why I don't see my custom error message. Here is how I have implemented the ApiRequestException:

1. I have implemented the ApiRequestException class:

   ```
   public class ApiRequestException extends RuntimeException {

     public ApiRequestException(String message) {
       super(message);
     }
   }
   ```
2. I have implemented an Exception handler:

   ```
   @ControllerAdvice
   public class ApiExceptionHandler {

     @ExceptionHandler(value = { ApiRequestException.class })
     public ResponseEntity<Object> handleApiRequestException(ApiRequestException e) {
       HttpStatus badRequestStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
       ApiRequestError apiRequestError = new ApiRequestError(badRequestStatus, e.getMessage());
       return ResponseEntity.status(badRequestStatus)
                            .body(apiRequestError);
     }
       }
   ```
3. Well, as you can see, the exception handler is using an ApiRequestError class. I have implemented this as well: It's just a class that stores a message-string and an httpStatus.

When debugging my application, I have verified that the exception handler is called. Setting a breakpoint inside my GET-Controller shows that the ApiRequestException is thrown. The exception is handled by the ExceptionHandler.

So, anyways, I cannot explain why there is no custom error message in my browser console, but instead what seems to be a default message generated by Spring Boot. Can somebody help?

===================================================

update:

As it turns out, this issue seems to be related to my frontend, not my backend. The code I have presented here works fine. I have tested this by logging the error message in the way described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71268028/why-does-a-get-request-with-fetch-api-log-a-server-response-error-message-into-t) follow-up question.

Comment: I think your issue is in frontend.

Comment: maybe.. I am using the fetch API to make the GET-request. Inside my browser console, I receive an error message of the form `GET url-with-get-parameters 400`, which is empty. Inside the code, the fetch is underlined, saying: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400`. So, to me it seems to be a problem with my server, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add these configs in the properties file?

```
server.error.include-message=always
server.error.include-binding-errors=always
```

Comment: thx for your help, Faramarz! I have tried this out, but it takes no effect on my problem. I do see an error message in my console though - it's just that it is not the error message I expect to see. It does not have a message body. I don't know, maybe the problem is in my frontend.

Comment: Your code seems OK, maybe the problem is in another part of the code, any way exactly with the same way I handled errors in this repository `https://github.com/faramarzaf/SurenaRestApi`  you can check it out. I hope It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thx for the advice, but this does not seem to be it. I have the impression that Spring Boot has some overall exception handler that is being called after my custom ApiExceptionHandler.