# Why does a GET request with fetch API log a server response error message into the browser console?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, fetch-api

I am using the fetch-API to send a GET request to a Spring Boot backend. The request looks somewhat like this:

```
  const response = await fetch(url);
  if (response.status === 200) {
      // do something
  } else {
      response.json().then(response => console.log(response));
  }
```

In case that I send a valid request, i.e. the url passed into fetch() is valid, everything works fine. In case that I pass an invalid url into fetch(), however, two things appear to be happenning:

1. A serer response message is thrown:

[image: server response error]

2. My Spring Boot backend return a ResponseEntity with a custom error message as body. This error message is logged inside the else-block of the above code snippet:

[image: backend error response]

While I do expect the second point to be happenning, I cannot explain the first. I don't understand why this server-response error is logged into my browser console. I do have a few catch-blocks inside my code, something like:

```
const response = await fetch(url).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

As far as I know, however, fetch only throws an error if a network connection error occurred or similar. A response code not equal to 200 does not result in fetch throwing an error. So, as I said, I don't know where this error message comes from and I was hoping that somebody does, maybe it is something generic to the fetch API that I just don't know?

Comment: I would suppose this comes from the browser, not from your code.

Comment: @MrUpsidown it seems that you are right! I am using Chrome. When enabling "Hide network messages" in my dev tools, the error message is not visible any longer. I find this behavior a bit disturbing, do you know of a reason why it is usually enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using "try catch" to better capture errors.

If the response is positive and it's a json, use a "then" after the fetch.

```
try {
  const response = await fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
  // do something
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

If you're getting a 400 error, check the api documentation to see if you're passing the parameter incorrectly. or if that is not the route